# поиск корневого элемента ассоциативного массива

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Здравствуйте, гугл не помог. Задача: подняться вверх по дереву ассоциативного массива любого уровня вложенности до корневого элемента. Обратную задачу успешно решил сам (правда, некоторые участники ресурса помогали мне избавиться в коде от глобальной переменной в рекурсии). Подскажите хотя бы как определить первого предка элемента.
Упрощенный пример:

```
array(
 [1] = array(
   [id]=>1,
   [parent_id] = 0
   [children] = array(
     [34] => array(
       [id] => 34,
       [parent_id] = 1,
       [children] = array(
        [7] => array(
         [id]=7
     )
   ) 
)
)
```

Например, для id=7 выстроить цепочку 7 -> 34 -> 1
Такое ощущение, что на php это вообще невозможно реализовать...

UPDATE: Обратная задача - поиск узла дерева:

```
public static function findNode(&$dataset,$id) {
    if(isset($dataset[$id])) return $dataset[$id];
     foreach ($dataset as $value){
         if (isset($value['children'])) {
         $result=self::findNode($value['children'], $id);
         if ($result) return $result; 
         }
    }
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: А что вам мешает при рекурсии вглубь сохранять список путей?

Comment: Давайте ваш код поиска в глубину, вам покажут как развернуть результат.

Comment: @Bookin, обновил вопрос

Comment: @rjhdby, рекурсия вглубь нужна для совершенно других целей и никак не связана с вопросом. На данном этапе разработки я получаю массив, мне необходимо по заданному элементу вывести все его предки.

Comment: @Deus а элемент то вы как находите?

Comment: @rjhdby  Я обновил вопрос,добавил код. Код находит необходимый узел со всеми потомками.

Comment: Рекурсивно обходите массив, составляете карту ID - ID родителя. На основании карты восстанавливаете цепочку. Карта- массив соответствий (просто так принято называть).

Comment: @ ReinRaus, приветствую! Я так понял, что мне нужно сверху вниз проходить массив? Представьте себе, что некоторые узлы имеют несколько дочерних узлов, которые могут содержать свои узлы, а могут и не содержать. Как же так получается - невозможно пройти сразу снизу вверх? Т. е. в php дочерний элемент "не знает" какому узлу он принадлежит?

Comment: Конечно не знает. Как вариант при создании структуры Вы можете присваивать `parent_id` не число, а ссылку на родительский элемент. Таким образом можно сразу иметь правильную структуру, которая позволит решить требуемую задачу.